# How to filter a data grid view in accordance with one or multiple drop down list selections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

as the title states I am trying to filter a grid view based on one or multiple selections made among 4 drop down lists.  On a button click event I populate the grid view with the broadest set of information. From here I would like to have the grid view update as I make selections in the available drop down lists (4 in total).

While I feel like I could accomplish this through a series of if statements and a modified query for each condition, I feel like there should be a more efficient way this can be done. Below I have posted any pertinent code to this problem I am having.

html/asp code

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchOCFamily" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="FamilyLong" DataValueField="FamilyLong" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchOCRate" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="RateLong" DataValueField="RateLong" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchOCTerm" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="TermLong" DataValueField="TermLong" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchOCEnrollment" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="TypeDescription" DataValueField="TypeDescription" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; padding: 2px;">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvReverseSearchOC" runat="server" Width="99%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None"
                            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderCode" HeaderText="Order Code" SortExpression="OrderCode" Visible="True" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Net Price" HeaderText="Net Price" SortExpression="Net Price" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

page load event

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim RSQuery As String = "
        SELECT dDown.OrderCode, dDown.[Description], dDown.[Net Price]
        FROM (
              SELECT SKU.OrderCode AS OrderCode, SKU.[Description] AS [Description],
              (SELECT FORMAT(SKU.ListPrice * EnrollmentType.Multiplier, 'C')) AS [Net Price]
              FROM Enrollment
              INNER JOIN EnrollmentType ON Enrollment.EnrollmentTypeID = EnrollmentType.RecID
              INNER JOIN SKU ON EnrollmentType.TypeID = SKU.EnrollmentTypeID
              INNER JOIN SKUBuild ON SKU.SKU = SKUBuild.SKU
              WHERE (Enrollment.AccountNumber = '12345')
              AND (Enrollment.Active = 'yes')
              AND (SKU.[Description] IS NOT NULL AND NOT (SKU.[Description] = '&quot;&quot;'))
        ) AS dDown
        "
    pnlSearchOC.Visible = False
    PopSearchOCDDLs()
    PopGVSearchOC(RSQuery)
End Sub
```

Procedure to populate the gridview

```
Protected Sub PopGVSearchOC(ByVal query As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WarrantyConnectionString").ToString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            con.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If sdr.HasRows Then
                    dt.Load(sdr)
                    With gvReverseSearchOC
                        .DataSource = dt
                        .DataBind()
                        con.Close()
                    End With
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

I have one more procedure that populates the drop down lists but I don't believe it is relevant to my problem, I may be wrong.

I am looking for an elegant solution to update/filter my grid view based on the selections made in the drop down lists, any information in this regard would be much appreciated. If I am missing any necessary code I would be happy to supply it but I am pretty sure its all here.
Thanks for you time guys.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you can do this two ways.

You can pull the data table, and persist the table (but, this can be a bit heavy on browser memory. (but, you could use session() to hold that resulting table - but using session() often means that if the user opens two copies of the page, then things don't work well.

So, probably best to filer against the SQL you have. (I would put that SQL in a SQL server view - we really don't want all SQL code in-line, as it hard to maintain.

So, our logic:

No selections - show all data. Select 1, or 2 or 3 or 4 combo or filters, then we progressive add this extra conditions. So, blank = ignore, and some value = filter with given values.

So, we kind of need a code stub and approach that works for 1, or 10 filer options. In other words, if we don't find a easy way to "add up" the filters, then we have to write code that considers all combinations. (very bad).

And in this solution, we ALSO very much do NOT want to concatenate values into the SQL, since that opens up to not only SQL injection, but such code tends to get very messy in a hurry.

So, this approach:

Test the given filter control - if value, then add to our criteria, but STILL use correct parameters - no concatenation of USER input values ever!

I don't have your data, but let's just cook up a simple grid, and add a few filters. We will have 2 combo, and say one check box (for only Active Hotels).

So, we have this markup, nothing fancy:

```
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select City"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="180px"
                DataValueField="City"
                DataTextField="City" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Province"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboProvince" runat="server" Width="180px"
                DataValueField="Province"
                DataTextField="Province" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Must Have Description"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDescripiton" runat="server"  />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Show only Active Hotels"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActiveOnly" runat="server"  />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn"/>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdClear" runat="server" Text="Clear Fitler" CssClass="btn"/>
        </div>



        <div style="clear:both">
                <%-- this starts new line for grid --%>
        </div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"  CssClass="table" Width="60%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active"  />


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, we just drop in as many "divs", float them left for the filters. You can easily add more filter controls.

So, now our code to load up this stuff, is say this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadCombos()
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName")
        LoadGrid(cmdSQL)

    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadCombos()

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
        SqlCommand("SELECT City FROM tblHotels WHERE City is not null GROUP by City")
    cboCity.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    cboCity.DataBind()
    cboCity.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", "All"))

    cmdSQL.CommandText =
        "SELECT Province FROM tblHotels WHERE Province is not null GROUP by Province"
    cboProvince.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    cboProvince.DataBind()
    cboProvince.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", "All"))


End Sub

Sub LoadGrid(cmdSQL As SqlCommand)

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub


Public Function MyrstP(sqlCmd As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using sqlCmd
        sqlCmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        sqlCmd.Connection.Open()
        rstData.Load(sqlCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Again, quite simple - just some clean code to load up our combo, and the grid.

So, now we have this:

[image]

OK, so now the filter code. As noted, this can work if we have 2 or 20 filters. and you can add more over time - you don't have to change EXISTING code.

So, the code is like this - search button:

```
Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels"
    Dim strOrderBy As String = " ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim strWhere As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("")

    If cboCity.Text <> "All" Then
        ' city filter
        strWhere = "(City = @City)"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.Text
    End If

    If cboProvince.Text <> "All" Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Province = @Province)"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Province", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboProvince.Text
    End If

    ' must have description
    If chkDescripiton.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Description is not null)"
    End If

    If chkActiveOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Active = 1)"
    End If

    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strSQL &= " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If

    strSQL &= " " & strOrderBy
    cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL
    LoadGrid(cmdSQL)

End Sub
```

So, note the "pattern". For each control you add, you have a if/then block. You check existing where clause (might be none), and add " AND " to the where clause. You then add parameters to the SQL command object.

MANY fail to realize, that you can add parameters to the command object, and you don't even need to have set what the SQL source for the SQL command object is!!! - they are separate concepts.

So, with above, we are free to check/select or whatever for the filter, and then hit search button.

The above approach works if you have 2 or 25 optional controls.

And very importantly, we NEVER in ANY case ever concatenate user input into that SQL string - only ever use parameters , so this approach is SQL injection safe.

Comment: Hello Albert, I would like to thank you for your reply. I was able to follow your example however in the end when I go to test this, I am able to make all the selections I need in my drop down lists but when I hit search I don't know if the site is timing out, but the panel I have the gridview on disappears and I am left with an exception error "System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded." and the grid view doesn't actually "Filter" anything.

Comment: update your web.config maxRequestLength/maxAllowedContentLength values

Comment: Well, in code you could do a debug.print (strSQL) as a test, and see what the sql looks like and spits out (your have to possible mess with VS as to if your debug.print outputs to  immediate window - but, assuming you used debug.print before, try a debug.print of the sql you generating.   We assume the grid worked before adding any filters.  As noted, you might want to save the "base" query you have as a view, as then the sql example becomes a rather simple select * from MyView, and THEN you can build up + add the where clause. You could check maxRequestlengh, but we assume grid works.

Comment: The other issue? We might want to skip loading of all rows. I mean, a grid view is good for about 1000 rows of data max. After that, you pushing out WAY TOO much rows of data. So, you might on first load have some critera of id  = 0 to return no rows. You can still get/have the heading to show if you add ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true". So, more then say 1000 rows, and you sending too much data. At 1000 rows you can use a data pager, but even then, you need to introduce sql server paging.

Comment: So, without filters, what is the estimated row count? As noted, you don't want to send much more then 1000 rows of data to a grid view (besides, kind of torture to users if you display that much data anyway). As a stop gap, and band aid, you could for now introduce a data pager, and thus limit display rows to say 40 rows.

Comment: Hey Albert, So when the grid is originally populated on page load their are around 273 rows total. What ends up happening after I select values in the drop down lists is that the panel that holds the grid will disappear and when I open it again, I receive that exception error.  I then went into web.cofig and updated my maxRequestLength/maxAllowedContentLength and when I reopen the grid it is filled with many duplicate values and is very unresponsive and slow.

Comment: 200-300 rows? That should be ok. Note that filtering against a store proc can be done, but in general does NOT work well. I suggest you try creating a view - that is your base query. Then use the sample code, and use a SELECT * from MyView WHERE......... that should work fast, and I can't imagine that your query will take longer then 1/10th a second. 273 rows max is super hard to mess up and make slow. But, as noted, do try a view, and use that as the "base" sql, and then try adding the where clause + parameters as per sample code. . Possible slow data connection?

Comment: As noted, as a line of code RIGHT before you set the commandText, do a debug.print - take a quick look at the sql produced  - maybe it is wonkey. But, as noted, I would try using a plain jane view for the base query (without criteria).  (since a store proc will not have with great ease optional criteria /parameters). Then as per code, apply the where clause  + the parameters to the sql command object.

Comment: yes, just looking at your original query? Try saving that query as a view. Make sure the view as your base sql works in SSMS. Then in code, try using SELECT * FROM MyView - WHERE ... --- so save that base query as a view - does it run fast from SSMS? (it should).