# How to get data from gridview for condition?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview in asp.net and it has some booking id with the header booking_id in the position of 0 and I have a text input which i want to validate with the gridview data. Here is my code

```
For i As Integer = 0 To grdvreservedetails.Rows.Count - 1
                If txtbookingid.Text = grdvreservedetails.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text Then
                    Exit For
                    lblmsg.Text = "Success"
                Else
                    lblmsg.Text = "Not in grdv"
                End If
            Next
```

What I am getting only the last booking id for the condition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not always reliable. You could convert that first column to be a template field, and then include a label `<asp:label id='lblID' runat='server' text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  />` and then for each row `If CType(grdvreservedetails.Rows(i).FindControl("lblID"),Label).Text.ToLower.Trim() = txtbookingid.Text.ToLower.Trim() Then`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a value from the heading, or from a given row???

You can use the HeaderRow, if that is what you are looking for.

Say, this:

[image]

So, to get the first cell of the heading, I can do this:

```
    Debug.Print(GHotels.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Text)
```

Which of course would in above output "FirstName".

And, if you have templated controls in your header, then using .findControl

## Edit: simple search of grid

Ok, so  you have this bit of code:

For i As Integer = 0 To grdvreservedetails.Rows.Count - 1
If txtbookingid.Text = grdvreservedetails.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text Then
Exit For
lblmsg.Text = "Success"
Else
lblmsg.Text = "Not in grdv"
End If
Next

In above, when you get a match, you EXIT the for loop - your lblmsg.Text = "Success" never runs!!!

So, this would work:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To grdvreservedetails.Rows.Count - 1
    If txtbookingid.Text = grdvreservedetails.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text Then
         lblmsg.Text = "Success"
         Exit For
    Else
         lblmsg.Text = "Not in grdv"
    End If
 Next
```

So the above should work just fine.

On the other hand, we could consider to filter the whole grid, and thus not just display some label text on the form.

Comment: as per your table, suppose I want to search Albert in firstname column. I give input of Albert and serach the name in the gridview. Using mentioned code, I am only getting Shannon in serach result. Hope I can clear my issue.

Comment: Well the first part of question was only how to get and grab values from the header - as code shows no loop is required. Now you brought up a vast new and different issue - you want to search or filter the data - nothing in your post talked about searching - but I'll update this post with additional code to search and filter the grid

Comment: See my edit - you have a small logic bug in your for/next loop - (and my apologies - you are in effect searching the grid - just not filtering it!!!).

Comment: Also, see this post of mine - I give an example of how to filter a grid based on several controls and values (dropdowns). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72942848/how-to-filter-a-data-grid-view-in-accordance-with-one-or-multiple-drop-down-list/72943565?noredirect=1#comment128862081_72943565